# ggplot annotation in fixed place in the chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the following data into a ggplot bar chart.

```
structure(list(MEDIATYPE = c("BACKLIT TOWER", "BILLBOARDS", "BRIDGE PANEL", 
"BUILDING FACADES", "BUS SHELTER", "CANTILIVERS", "CYCLE SHELTER", 
"FOB", "FREE STANDING PANEL", "GANTRIES"), RENTAL = c(197, 278363, 
1423, 26, 35960, 6194, 70, 4845, 27, 9420)), .Names = c("MEDIATYPE", 
"RENTAL"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using the following code to render the chart.  It is working fine.  However the problem is the yaxis values keeps changing and the annotation at the top of the chart sometimes disappears or in other instances appears in the middle of the chart.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr) # str_wrap


ggplot(b, aes(x=reorder(MEDIATYPE,-RENTAL), y=RENTAL, fill=MEDIATYPE)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") + xlab("MEDIATYPE") + ylab("SPENDS") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 1)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=RENTAL), vjust = 0.5,hjust = 1, angle = 90, colour = "white",size = 3) + 
    ggtitle("MEDIAWISE SPENDS") + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.4), lineheight = 1, face = "bold")) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8, color = "black")) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95"))  +
    ggplot2::annotate(geom = "text", label = "Source:ABC Monitors", x = Inf, y = -Inf, color = "blue",size = 3,fontface = "italic",hjust = 1, vjust = -30)
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the position of the annotation?

Comment: Suggestion, you can put all themes into one theme(), code will be cleaner.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for the suggestion will certainly do.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about exactly what you want? You want the annotation test "Source: ABC Monitors" to not move? Do you want to set it as a fixed percent of the y-axis?

Comment: @MikeyMike The current code given above prints the annotation "Source:ABC Monitors" at the top right of the screen in blue color.  This is because of the hjust and vjust parameters.  However the vertical justification parameter depends on the values of the yaxis.  Whenever the values of the yaxis changes the annotation goes for a toss.  My question is if we can set dynamic parameters of vjust and hjust so that the annotation appears at the same location whichever way the x-axis and y-axis values swings.

Comment: The code you have appears to be working for me. I've adjusted the y-axis using `b$RENTAL <- runif(length(b$RENTAL),0,100)` and when I reran the `ggplot` code, I got the annotation in the same spot. Could you provide an example of when it doesn't work?

Comment: Does it have to be on the plot? How about subtitle or a caption? See https://rud.is/b/2016/03/16/supreme-annotations/

Comment: What about scaling all your outcome to between zero and one, so that the text are always added at say y=0.9, You would then need to alter the labels on the y-axis.

Comment: another option is to use `grid.text.` This just draws it on to the plot, rather than adding it to the ggplot object. The benefit is you can specify the x and y (which by default are from zero to one)to be at the same place in the plot window for all plots.. eg `grid::grid.text(label = "Source:ABC Monitors", x=1, y=0.9, hjust=1.2, vjust=5, gp=gpar(fontface = "italic", col = "blue",size = 3))`

Comment: @user20650 Thank you user20650. Though I did not use ur suggestion I did use grid.text from an example here in SO and it renders flawlessly in the console but my code downloads the graph from a shiny app and it just printed the label without a graph...so dropped using grid.text.  Many thanks again.

Comment: @zx8754 is a wonderful blog zx8754...I went through it yesterday itself, but had to rush hence could not thank you then.  Its truly a good resource... thank you.  I tried using caption...but due to some gaps in my code it was not rendering....but will certainly try again as it is really worth it....thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adjusting the position using hjust and vjust why not set the y-position to the tallest bar?

```
ggplot(b, aes(x=reorder(MEDIATYPE,-RENTAL), y=RENTAL, fill=MEDIATYPE)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + xlab("MEDIATYPE") + ylab("SPENDS") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=RENTAL), vjust = 0.5,hjust = 1, angle = 90, colour = "white",size = 3) + 
  ggtitle("MEDIAWISE SPENDS") + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.4), lineheight = 1, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8, color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95"))  +
  ggplot2::annotate(geom = "text", label = "Source:ABC Monitors", 
                    x = Inf, y = max(b$RENTAL), 
                    color = "blue",size = 3,fontface = "italic",hjust = 1, vjust = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks darren17...I did try realigning the y axis - but messed it up with the vjust.....this certainly works.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 7):

Extending @user20650's idea, `textGrob` allows the use relative coordinates, but use `annotation_custom` to restrict the grob to the plot panel.

```
b = structure(list(MEDIATYPE = c("BACKLIT TOWER", "BILLBOARDS", "BRIDGE PANEL", 
"BUILDING FACADES", "BUS SHELTER", "CANTILIVERS", "CYCLE SHELTER", 
"FOB", "FREE STANDING PANEL", "GANTRIES"), RENTAL = c(197, 278363, 
1423, 26, 35960, 6194, 70, 4845, 27, 9420)), .Names = c("MEDIATYPE", 
"RENTAL"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

# Try a different y range
#      b[2, 2] = 30000

library(ggplot2)
library(stringr) # str_wrap
library(grid)

label = textGrob(label = "Source:ABC Monitors", x = .95, y = 0.95, 
      just = c("right", "top"),
      gp=gpar(fontface = "italic", col = "blue",size = 3))

p = ggplot(b, aes(x=reorder(MEDIATYPE,-RENTAL), y=RENTAL, fill=MEDIATYPE)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") + xlab("MEDIATYPE") + ylab("SPENDS") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 1)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=RENTAL), vjust = 0.5,hjust = 1, angle = 90, colour = "white",size = 3) + 
    ggtitle("MEDIAWISE SPENDS") + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.4), lineheight = 1, face = "bold")) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8, color = "black")) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95"))  +
    annotation_custom(label, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Sandy Muspratt.  I did try using textGrob with annotate-custom from an example in SO - but again did not try specifying the x and y axis values in the label itself...though I must admit i have never used textGrob.  I found darren7 suggestion pretty straight forward and have used it.  Thanks a ton Sandy Muspratt for the suggestions.

Comment: No worries. Darren's is a simple solution.